# How to create a id column based on change in state in previous column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame similar to this example

```
df<- structure(data.frame(ref<-c(rep (10047,11),rep(10050,9)),state<-c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)),.Names=c("ref", "state")) 

df[5:16,]
   ref   state
  10047     0
  10047     1
  10047     0
  10047     1
  10047     1
  10047     1
  10047     0
  10050     1
  10050     1
  10050     1
  10050     1
  10050     0
```

I would like to create an ID column that:

- Has a value of 0 where the state is 0
- Pastes the ref and some unique id (e.g. "_001") when state is 1 and keeps the same id for rows where there are consecutive states of 1
- changes the unique identifier (e.g. increases to "_002") for each new series of 1s.

I want the end result to look like the equivalent of adding this column

```
  df$id<-c("0","0","10047_001","10047_001" ,"0","10047_002","0", "10047_003","10047_003","10047_003", "0", "10050_001", "10050_001","10050_001","10050_001","0","0", "10050_002","0","10050_003")

df[5:16,]
 ref state        id
10047     0         0
10047     1 10047_002
10047     0         0
10047     1 10047_003
10047     1 10047_003
10047     1 10047_003
10047     0         0
10050     1 10050_001
10050     1 10050_001
10050     1 10050_001
10050     1 10050_001
10050     0         0
```

> 

Thanks

Comment: `library(data.table);setDT(df);df[,rid:=rleid(state),][state==1, id:=paste(ref, rleid(rid), sep = "_"),][,rid:=NULL,]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base R` can use try with `rle` and `ave` to create the sequence for each `ref`, then with `ifelse` and `paste` get the expected output.

```
 i1 <- with(df, ave(state==1, ref, FUN= function(x) inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), values[values] <- seq_along(values[values])))))
 ifelse(i1!=0, paste(df$ref, sprintf("%03d", i1), sep="_"), i1)
 #[1] "0"         "0"         "10047_001" "10047_001" "0"         "10047_002" "0"         "10047_003" "10047_003" "10047_003" "0"         "10050_001" "10050_001"
 #[14] "10050_001" "10050_001" "0"         "0"         "10050_002" "0"         "10050_003"
```